# Phalcon\Assets\Exception: Non-free csssminifier not available

Tags: php, minify, phalcon

Just installed latest WAMP 2.5 after clean install on win7. Have added latest PhalconPHP extension 1.3.3 x64. Works ok. Am using Mruz Base App 2.0 https://github.com/mruz/base-app and older version that was working fine with previous Wamp 2.2e install. I am getting an error from Phalcon telling me "Phalcon\Assets\Exception: Non-free csssminifier not available". This error is slightly confusing. Am I missing a dependency or something?

Answer (score 0):

[See this issue](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/pull/2774).

You must build phalcon with `--without-non-free` option.

Comment: I think that answer would apply to Phalcon installed on a UNIX OS. On Windows Phalcon comes as a DLL and is compiled by PHP - you don't seem to be able to "build" it on Windows.

Comment: my answer is mistake. sorry.

Comment: No problem. I am thinking it is a bug with the windows version.

Comment: I suggest watch [this issue](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2947) to you. The problem is to keep Free License of phalcon.So it is not a bug, but i think it will be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks @alu that issue was created by me under my gh user. So yes I will be watching it :)